# Codomain and range of onto Functions

Tags: functions

Is the codomain and range of an onto function the same? As far as I understand, if $f:A\to B$, range is all possible values in B. So if it's an onto function, then all values in B must be mapped to something in A right? Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the codomain and range of an onto function the same?

Yes, by definition a function $f:A\to B$ is onto if the range ($f(A)$) equals the codomain ($B$).

> So if it's an onto function, then all values in B must be mapped to something in A right? Am I correct?

I'm not sure you wrote what you meant to write. All values in $B$ must be mapped *to by something in $A$*, yes.

Comment: thanks! sorry I didn't know onto functions were defined like that. I was taught only the definition that a function is onto if " All values in B must be mapped to by something in A"

Comment: @Teerex ... but those two things are semantically identical. You *were* taught that definition. They are the same, just with different notation. It's worth thinking about a little.